# SQL+PHP: передаю сегодняшнюю дату, получаю нулевой день

Tags: php, mysql

На сервере выполняется "UPDATE player SET timer = "2019-06-17 07:53:49" WHERE player_id = 2;" на ура, а когда то же самое делаю через php (дату генерирую только), в базу записывается все по нулям (значение "0000-00-00 00:00:00" вместо "2019-06-17 07:53:49"). Что-то не так с функцией date? Что я делаю не так?

```js
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) as Amount FROM player WHERE player_id='.$_GET['viewer_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $result = $data[0]['Amount'];

    $date_as_str = (string)date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    if ($result == 0)
 {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO player (player_id, posx, posy, room_id, timer) VALUES ('.$_GET['viewer_id'].', 0, 0, 1,"'.$date_as_str.'");');
  
 }
    else
 {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE player SET timer = ".$date_as_str." WHERE player_id = '.$_GET['viewer_id'].';');
  
 
 }

    $stmt->execute();
    $pdo = null;

    echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строку

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE player SET timer = ".$date_as_str." WHERE player_id = '.$_GET['viewer_id'].';');
```

Нужно изменить так

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE player SET timer = "'.$date_as_str.'" WHERE player_id = '.$_GET['viewer_id'].';');
```

У вас пропущены символы одинарных кавычек.